# Bluetooth Low Energy

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, intel-edison

a device uses intel edison which has *BLE. Suppose the BLE is programmed to send the data from a sensor to an app on cellphn.. I hv other data from another sensor. Can the same BLE be simultaneously programmed to send the data from the second sensor too?

Comment: Are both sensors connected to the Intel edison? How is data sent from the sensor? Is it being put in characteristic value and then the cellp hone app reads the characteristic value?

Comment: Are the sensors connected to Intel edison? Then use the characterisitic to pair with the app and send the other sensor's data also. Or you can receive data from both sensors simultaneously too. Depends on what you want.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is that you have different characteristics for the sensors which must have been defined by the hardware manufacturers. Then enable the sensors and register to get notifications. Refer to https://github.com/devunwired/accessory-samples/blob/master/BluetoothGatt/src/com/example/bluetoothgatt/MainActivity.java

This brilliant code will help you understand the intricate details for using BLE with Android.